# Having trouble with Tomcat running a python script

Tags: java, python, tomcat

I am trying to run a python script from a java bean on a Tomcat server. The code that executes this looks like this:

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(test);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream()));
String line = in.readLine();
String response = "";
while(line != null){
    response += line;
    line += in.readLine();
}
child.waitFor();
```

The error I receive is in the form of two pop-ups one that reads "Could not determine the package or source package name." and the other is an OS error from Ubuntu stating an internal error has occurred with the python script. 
Is there something in Tomcat that needs to be setup in order for it to be able to execute a python script on the local system?

Some background, I need the python script to dynamically generate an image based on data selected by the user. My test system is Ubuntu 12.04, I will be deploying on a CentOS system.

Comment: It is important to know the value of `test` (the command being given).  It is also important to know what this produces when you type the command directly on a command line.  That is probably your error that the system is not configured correctly for the command being given.

Comment: I have taken the value of "test" and copied and pasted it into a terminal window and it executes as I expect and without issue. I believe the system is configured correctly to execute the command being given, I think the problem is Tomcat is not configured properly to run a python script but I am not a Tomcat expert so I am not sure how to check Tomcat's configuration.